# How to tell Vite to exclude a subset of files in a directory from build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, rollup

I created a new Vue app using `npm create vue`. During runtime this app fetches a configuration and reads a string from it. This string represents the name of a component to render inside the app. Those dynamic components live inside a "pluggable" directory

```
.
└── src
    ├── App.vue
    └── pluggables
        ├── ThisFoo.vue
        └── ThatBar.vue
```

So basically what the App.vue file does is

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, shallowRef, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const pluggableComponent = shallowRef();

onMounted(() => {
  // fetch configuration
  const componentName = "ThisFoo"; // extract from configuration

  pluggableComponent.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./pluggables/${componentName}.vue`));
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>Pluggable below:</div>
  <component :is="pluggableComponent" />
</template>
```

I have access to the configuration file during build time and know which components I need during runtime and which ones to consider as "dead code" based on this configuration. Is there a way to tell Vite to exclude the unused components from the build?

E.g. exclude the whole pluggables directory but include the required components from the pluggables directory

> vite build --exclude ./src/pluggables/** --include ./src/pluggables/ThisFoo.vue

or by creating a custom Vite build function I can call during CI/CD and pass in an array of component names.

Comment: Likely should be a glob that excludes these names. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import-caveats

Comment: But which is the correct option in the vite.config file for `import.meta.glob`? Most samples I see do it inside the code but just to import multiple files at once. I want to exclude specific files during build time

Comment: Actually, these files will be built into separate chunks right? So even if some of them are dead code, they still will not affect your main bundle size. So what is your reason for excluding them?

Comment: @Duannx why are they not affecting the build size? They live in the build directory :S I want to exclude them because customers should not be able to see components other customers might be using

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To exclude some files from the build process you can mark them as external files by using the [external config](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external) of Rollup

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";

const filesNeedToExclude = ["src/pluggables/Comp1.vue", "src/pluggables/Comp2.vue"];

const filesPathToExclude = filesNeedToExclude.map((src) => {
  return fileURLToPath(new URL(src, import.meta.url));
});

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },

  build: {
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        ...filesPathToExclude
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you thing about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75494333/19698303 Any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: I am assuming this answer does not work when bundling a library right? this didn't work for me.

Comment: @StephaniBishop did you find a solution for library mode?

Comment: Looking for a fix too.

Answer (score 2):

I end up just using the `{ "exclude": [] }` in `tsconfig.json`. 
And it worked for me. *(Not sure if that is the proper way.)*
*(using React + Typescript, not vue)*

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412767/how-to-tell-vite-to-exclude-a-subset-of-files-in-a-directory-from-build/75480206#75480206) answer I came up with the following solution to exclude everything in the directory except the desired components

```
import { readdirSync } from 'node:fs'
import { join } from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

function getPluggablesToExclude(): string[] {
  const rawPluggablesToInclude = process.env.PLUGGABLES; // !! set this env variable in the CI pipeline !!

  if (!rawPluggablesToInclude) { // if missing, exclude nothing
    return [];
  }

  const pluggablesToInclude = rawPluggablesToInclude.split(',').map(component => `${component}.vue`);

  const pluggablesDirectoryPath = join(__dirname, 'src', 'pluggables');
  const filesInPluggablesDirectory = readdirSync(pluggablesDirectoryPath);

  const filesToExclude = filesInPluggablesDirectory.filter(file => !pluggablesToInclude.includes(file));

  return filesToExclude.map(file => join(pluggablesDirectoryPath, file));
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        ...getPluggablesToExclude()
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

So all I have to do is to set the env variable in my CI pipeline. If I skip this step, the build will include every component.

Comment: This should work. But there is a better but harder way which is using regex in the list. You can use a negative regex to check the file name does not in the array so it will be marked as external. Here is the regex generated from chat GPT :) Test it before using `^(?!${fileNames.join("|")}$).*$`