# Sveltekit routes for Development mode only

Tags: sveltekit

Is there any better ways to make some sveltekit routes only available during the dev mode only?

Like I often need to test components from a separate route. I don't want them to be available on the production.

```
/routes
   - /home
   - /contact
   - /Test <- route for testing other components.
```

You might ask why I need separate route where I can use the components on the route where they are used? Well this is just a simple example. My project is too much complex and requires many manual inputs to even get started. So each time I change the component I need to put all inputs again. So I made a separate test route where I used dummy inputs.

Currently what I do is add the route folders in the .env file which doesn't push them to github. But what If my local backup is lost.

I am looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried telling rollup to exclude?  In vite.config.ts, set `build.rollupOptions.external` to `[ "path/to/routefolder/to/exclude" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution with parameter matching

### Context

A quick solution is to have a route which is only matched when in development mode. In other words, "/test" will only match with a valid route when the [dev](https://kit.svelte.jp/docs/modules#$app-environment-dev) environment variable ($app/environment) is true. You could do this by manually writing redirects in "+page.server.ts", but this is tedious. Instead, we can create a rule for certain routes to only be valid in dev mode.

SvelteKit supports [matching](https://kit.svelte.jp/docs/advanced-routing#matching) for routes. This means you can have dynamic routes that match certain constrains. For example, if you have a "book/[page]" route, where you only want the page slug to be a valid integer, you can add a parameter match by changing the route name to "book/[page=integer]". Then in "src/params", you can add a definition for this matcher in "integer.ts".

### Solution

1. Create the folder "src/params" if it doesn't already exist, and then create a file called "dev.ts". Now SvelteKit will register "dev" as a valid matcher.
2. Add this param matcher and edit it how you like. I used include here to make all routes with "test" inside them match.

   ```
   import { dev } from '$app/environment';
   import type { ParamMatcher } from '@sveltejs/kit';

   // Change to whatever you want
   const nameOfRoute = "Test";

   export const match: ParamMatcher = (param) => {
     // Doesn't have to be include, but needs to return a boolean
     return dev && param.includes(nameOfRoute);
   };
   ```
3. Change your route to use this matcher: "routes/Test" -> "routes/[test=dev]".
4. Test going to that route with "npm run preview" and it should return a 404. Of course this still bundles it into production however :(.

## Regarding exclusion from build

Trying [this method for vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412767/how-to-tell-vite-to-exclude-a-subset-of-files-in-a-directory-from-build) you will get an error saying you can't exclude entry modules. Trying to make the folder itself an external in vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['tests/unit/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ["src/routes/Test"]
        }
    }
});
```

Doesn't seem to do anything from my tests.
I will edit with a solution if I find one.