The preferred way to place content inside a custom element as an input to the component?
I'm trying to develop a syntax highlighting web component and it will take content placed inside it and syntax highlight it.  So something like this:
<fs-highlight data-line-numbers="true" data-language="html">
   any content here ....
</fs-highlight>

This is a prototype implementation and it gets and highlights the content within the element like this:
this._code = hljs.highlight(this.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+/g, ''), {
        language: this.language,
      }).value;


And I'm wondering whether it's correct / fine to use this.innerHTML to grab the content?
The implementation is not using a slot, so the content is not rendered within the element.
However in this demo, vite fails to compile the element.  However I'm wondering if that's just due to how the Stackblitz vite compilation works ...(I put a non trivial amount of markup within the element to test it out...)?
Perhaps with local compilation and publishing this goes away ... Thoughts?

You have two problems:

Style is not working

❌ Problem: That is happening because you style is outside of your webcomponent!
✅ Solution: To fix it is just to put the style of @highlight.js inside your component!

Error from vite at console

❌ Problem: Actually it is not a problem but an expected behaviour of vite!
✅ Solution: There are two possible solutions.
One is to scape the script tag on html:
...

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono:ital,wght@1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
&lt;script type="module" src="./my-timer.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
<style> ... </style>

...

So by this way vite will skip the script render but you need to replace by the correct character.
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  const code = this.innerHTML
    .replace(/^\s+/g, '')
    .replace(/\&gt\;/g, '>')
    .replace(/\&lt\;/g, '<');
  this._code = hljs.highlightAuto(
    code, 
    this.language 
      ? { language: this.language } 
      : undefined
  ).value;
}
render() {
  const code = this.language 
    ? html`<code class="language-${this.language}">${unsafeHTML(this._code)}</code>`
    : html`<code>(${unsafeHTML(this._code)})</code>`;
  return html`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/styles/default.min.css" />
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <pre>${code}</pre>
  `;
}

And another solution is to exclude this file from build at vite.config.js.
Some helpful links:

https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external
How to tell Vite to exclude a subset of files in a directory from build?


Hi - I tried your answer, and it does highlight the markup, so it looks like it's working correctly, however vite still produces the compiler as can be seen in the console ... thoughts?  ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jzduuu?file=src%2Fmy-element.ts

This is the expected behaviour of vite it'll render all script tags automaticly anyway I'll update my answer with a simple approach to solve it. However I belive that another way to solve it is to change your vite.config.ts adding a configuration to exclude this script of your bundling in you vite configuration! Vite uses rollup underwoood so that is the configuration https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external here is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412767/how-to-tell-vite-to-exclude-a-subset-of-files-in-a-directory-from-build!

If I understand correctly vite is objecting to the script inside the fs-highlight tag not resolving.  Now I was hoping that vite would ignore the content all together, because authors using the component should be able to put any language, markup, etc. that they want within the component body without it generating errors or side effects.  Do you know if there's a way to achieve this?

I belive that to another languages it'll works nice! But specially for HTML you need to be carefully in two moments during the build, due to vite trying to add this assets at your bundle and in execution time because the browser will try to fetch all those assets like font and script! I belive that the best solution is scape HTML tags!

Yes in some cases users will be able to escape all the HTML ... But in some cases they will just want to paste code into the element and have it work ... I was assuming initially that since the element design is not using a slot then the browser and the build will not "Interpret" the html ... and treat it more like static text ... I'm hoping there is a way to be able to include any type of markup within the element and have the browser and build just ignore it ...

Now that I think about it (As you are pointing out)  ... the index.html file seems the be the file that is producing the vite build issue ... so perhaps just excluding it will do the trick ... I'll try ...

I ended up trying to exclude index.html from tsconfig.json and it did not work, so I asked a separate question about this, since tsconfig.json is the only compilation file that stackblitz exposes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78355022/excluding-a-file-from-the-vite-lit-element-typescript-build

When you do
this._code = hljs.highlight(this.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+/g, ''), {
        language: this.language,
      }).value;

that async loaded innerHTML might not be there yet. That is why Tools like Lit, Stencil, Shoelace and the 60+ add methods like parsedCallback or even just force shadowDOM on my.
All you need is to wait for that innerHTML in lighjtDOM to be parsed;
long explanation: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7/edit

The link returns a 404 ...

Are you saying that there is another method within the lit lifecycle that we should use to retrieve the components innerHTML to make sure that it has loaded?
