Excluding a file from the vite lit element typescript build?
In this lit element stackblitz demo the compilation produces an error saying that a script could not be loaded.
This is OK since the element that the script is pasted within is going to syntax highlight that content, and it's not meant to be part of what the browser renders.  More on that in this question..
So I figured if the index.html file can be excluded from the build, that would solve the issue, and I tried the exclude property in tsconfig.json, however no love.
  "compilerOptions": {
    "exclude": ["index.html"],


Thoughts?
